# ReSharper: how to NOT insert spaces after keywords, or completely disable formatting

Tags: configuration, resharper, code-formatting

When I type, for example, 'internal' and press Enter on autocomplete list item, a space is inserted automatically after the word i.e.: 'internal '. Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Or, even better, maybe there is a way to disable completely code formatting "part" of ReSharper? I do like its code inspection features and tools, but I think it's a bad idea to get used to its autoformatting features.

**Edit:**

To be clear, by *autoformatting* here, I mean not whole document formatting (which is indeed a good feature), but rather autocomplete part of it, i.e. then you select 'Close' in autocomplete ReSharper produces 'Close();\n' while standard VS output will be 'Close'.

Comment: I don't have an answer for how to disable space insertion, but I don't think autoformatting is a bad idea. Ff you are coding in a team, it is really nice to have consistent style between the developers. This is something autoformatting will encourage. Also ReSharper lets you tweak the style settings quite a bit.

Comment: Agreed. Tweak the auto-formatting settings so that you and your team are happy with the results. Consistently-formatted code is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looking under the highlighted areas in the screenshot and see if that helps you. I don't know any other way to disable auto completion.

FWIW, I agree with Holstebroe and Roger that you should find auto complete settings that work for you and your team instead of disabling them. Common code formatting is really nice to have.

Comment: Well, seems like it's impossible achieve that I want, probably it's just the way ReSharper works, you use it or you don't (if you don't  like it). Seems it plain try and decide :)

Comment: can't see screencast anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

This happens because ReSharper intellisense is enabled by default. If you switch it to VS intellisense (ReSharper - Options - Enviroment - Intellisense), this behavior will disappear (and all ReSharper intellisense improvements too).